# Outlook rule fails on mails with empty subject

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, email-filter

when creating rules for automatic forwarding emails in Outlook 2013 i noticed that these rules fail, if an email with a blank subject line (no subject) is recieved.
All other emails work fine, just an empty subject line makes the rule fail.
Any hint on how to solve/debug this issue?
Thanx

Comment: It might help if you describe what the rules look at and do.

Comment: as described: they FORWARD the emails to another address. that's it, nothing extra.
so a test rule is: forward all incoming mails to xxx@yyy.com.
it fails on blank subject emails...

Comment: Seems to be a bug. Most you can do to report it and hope it'll be fixed (or try a newer version if it works better).

Comment: @Máté Juhász: a bug, really? this is so obviously one of the most basic things someone **HAS** to test in development... btw: Outlook 2013 on Windows 10, both fully patched.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Exchange account?

I checked this on my Outlook 2013  on Win 10. Create following rule:
[image]

Messages without subject can be forwarded, too.

[image]

Please check whether your rules are same with me. 
You can also delete the rule and create the rule on the web mail to see if it helps.

[Similar thread here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6639268a-eaf0-434c-893d-5fbc1b00d3e7/rules-not-working-with-outlook-2016-client-for-pcs?forum=outlook).  Add the condition “stop processing more rules” could help avoid rule conflicts.

Comment: No, i use IMAP accounts. Tried different accounts and also the "stop processing more rules". My rule is like yours - but still generating an error on mails with empty subject. Maybe you could try and check this on an additional IMAP account?

Comment: I tested with IMAP account and was interested to find that this issue can be reproduced. No subject email will not be forwarded successfully. Same behavior for Outlook 2013 and Outlook 2016.I'd like to recommend you visit the Outlook user voice forum: https://outlook.uservoice.com/ to vote your feedback.

Comment: Well, outlook.uservoice.com answered this:
**Thank you for submitting feedback to Outlook Uservoice.  This site is for submitting feature requests.  If you are experiencing a problem with the product and need assistance, please post to the appropriate forum:

(Primary) Outlook consumer issues, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/outlook
Outlook 2016 Insider builds, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_insider
Outlook for IT and Exchange professionals, https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=outlook**

Comment: strange....Let me do more test. Would you mind providing the link which you posted in UserVoice forum?

Comment: https://email.feedback-poweredby.uservoice.com/c/eJyFkE1uxCAMhU-T7BgB4ScsWFSq5hojB0yCkoERkE6PX2bUTVeVvHiyPz_Zz1tOmYQxWulnZThFFFrBjXHwM-NSUMpnJRQ1OAh6VixfOTq8uHwfN-sXqQPzWvIgzExBwhS0EKABOYJ042G31h51mD4Gfu2Vz3bkvF_-GPV-yOW81y4mzqWh5Jcj_ThF-pA8Y_L5-SLqua5YW8zpzc-KSUUlCfGbLOdK2gaNHAi-kpZJOQ8kWMrLYcP0snpC8TGtw3RtBdze5c1lj8P0yZ10BvXS30VnKNPTYvTsFhYU1yrg-GfB_osXG1PIPba6Ew8NU0O3pbi_w2u2no9HLg3L7Y61woo_1DeANQ

But the post is not visible to the public and the moderators answered as reported (see above)...

Comment: i started a thread on Microsoft TechNet: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3bc3a15f-e831-4dd9-9c85-e4be6976ecee/rule-error-on-forwarding-mails-with-empty-subject?forum=outlook